# Java Downcasting of extending class

Tags: java, downcast

Why this code is not working? When i casting, I get ClassCastExeption
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: A cannot be cast to B
    at HelloWorld.main

```
public class HelloWorld
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    B b1 = (B)new A();
    b1.a();
   }
}

public class A
{
  public void a (){
  System.out.println("A.a");
  }
  public void b (){
  System.out.println("A.b");
  }
}

public class B extends A{ 
}
```

Comment: Because you cannot cast an `A` to a `B`.

Comment: I suggest you to read the basics of inheritance and how it works you cannot cast parent to child....

Comment: You're declaring B is a kind of A. That doesn't mean A is a kind of B. Then you're saying 'this A is a B'. Compiler complains.

Comment: You _probably_ wanted it the other way round: `A b1 = new B();
    b1.a();`

Comment: Yes, its upcasting. And what about downcasting in this example?

Comment: @pvg The compiler doesn't complain. The JVM does.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)

Comment: @xehpuk the jvm and you complain :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Casting can't always be done in both ways.

If you are creating an Animal, by calling "new Animal()", you are creating an Object that is an Animal, but it cannot be downcasted to Dog. Because it's not a dog.

However when you create a Dog by calling "new Dog()", then you can upcast it to "Animal" and downcast it back to "Dog".

```
Dog dog = new Dog();         
Animal animal = dog;         //upcasting to Animal
if(animal instanceof Dog){ // testing if the Animal is a Dog       
    Dog dog2 = (Dog) animal; //downcast
}
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you! Downcasting possible only after upcasting! Now its clear!

Comment: @A.Kashnikov And should almost never be used anyway.

Comment: right ! he should exercise more about inheritance concept in java to understand this well.

Comment: @chrylis, yes. But its interesting to know such details